# Is twisted conch available in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, twisted.conch

I noticed twisted.conch is not part of dist3.py for python 3.Is it not yet migrated to python 3? I dont find any recent updates on the same when i search. I was planning to use it to establish multiple telnet sessions which ll help asses logs in my django app and also help debug live django application using manhole.

IS there an alternate i can use for my use case?
I checked out asyncio. However, my understanding is it might freeze the application during debug which would not suit my need.do correct me if my understanding is wrong..

pls point me to latest twisted package for python 3 with conch support if available . if not, do you have any alternate suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the [Python 3 milestone](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/milestone/Python-3.x) I guess they are not there yet; there are tickets open for the Conch component.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Do you have any suggestions on the alternatives i have for conch ?